# Which should I upgrade for programming in Laptop, RAM or SSD?

Tags: processor, memory, hard-disk, ssd

I have a Lenovo 320 laptop which has core i3 processor, 7th generation and 4GB RAM. Now for Programming what should I upgrade? Should I upgrade 4GB to 8GB or add 250GB SSD with 1TB HDD? I am really confused. Thanks in advance. I want to use the laptop for official tasks. and may have to use dual boot. in this case, what should I do?

Comment: @M.ahmed It looks like you have two accounts now. If you'd like to merge them, please use the [contact link](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/contact) and use the "merge" option.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by programming. Are you going to use this laptop for an intro to programming class?

If so, its fine as is and you shouldn't need to upgrade anything.

If you want your computer to run better for development purposes, my recommendation is that when you run whatever code you have written keep an eye on your resource usage in the Windows task manager. If you see that you're RAM usage is high then get more RAM. If you see that you are reading a lot from disk, then get an SSD if you feel like your program is taking too long to run.